# Data is inserted twice in database jpa/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Couldn't find what is wrong with inserting data in mySQL database using Spring data, JPA, hibernate and mySQL. It is inserting data twice in database.

The root-context.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.db">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <jdbc:embedded-database type="HSQL" id="dataSource"/>

    <!-- <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/jpa"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean> -->

  <!--   <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean> -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
        id="entityManagerFactory">      
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.db.entity"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
         <!--  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/> -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.project.db.repository"/>
</beans>
```

The servlet-context.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.db" />    

</beans:beans>
```

My @Entity class is:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id ;

    private String name ;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

JPA repository is:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.project.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

And, finally, @Service class is:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.project.entity.User;
import com.project.repository.UserRepository;

@Transactional
@Service
public class InitDbService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository  userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Ali");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

The above code works without errors/exceptions; database/table is also created but data is inserted into Entity/table twice when I see that in mySQL database. 
Project is at [github](https://github.com/arshadalisoomro/spring-jap).

Console output is:

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.project.db.WebAppInitializer@1867584]
Sep 2, 2015 12:50:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Sep 02 12:50:17 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Hibernate: drop table if exists users
Hibernate: create table users (id integer not null auto_increment, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: insert into users (name) values (?) // first time inserting here and
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5633 ms
Sep 2, 2015 12:50:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 02 12:50:23 PKT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.project.db.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 02 12:50:23 PKT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 02 12:50:23 PKT 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
Hibernate: insert into users (name) values (?) // Second time inserting here 
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springDispatcher': initialization completed in 1483 ms
Sep 2, 2015 12:50:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/db] is completed
```

Comment: Could it be that you have two Spring contexts, both containing an `InitDbService` bean, which in turn inserts one time each? With Spring MVC one typically has a servlet-context, which creates beans for controller, and an applicationContext, which creates every bean that is not a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a chance here since I see that you are using Spring MVC.

With Spring MVC, you have a servlet-context which defines the controllers, and an applicationContext for other beans. It might be that you are scanning for beans other than controllers in the servlet-context, which in turn will give you two beans of `InitDbService`, both running their @PostConstruct-method, inserting into the database.

This can be solved by defining component-scan like this:

servlet-context (after placing controllers and controllers only in a separate package):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.project.controller" />
```

applicationContext:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.project">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: see I have pasted root-context and servlet-context can you update your answer accordingly???

Comment: From what I can tell your servlet-context scan isn't limited to controllers only, which means that both your applicationContext and your servlet-context will scan and create a bean for InitDbService. Use the include-filter as outlined above to make sure your servlet-context only creates beans for your controllers.

Comment: I ave made changes according to your suggestions but still the same issue insertion is happening twice.

Comment: Don't know why? but I put controllers in separate package then WebAppInit.class and made changes according to your suggestions and whooo it works fine.

Comment: I don't think the include filter works the way I expected it to then.. The setup with a separate package is the one that's used at my work, someone probably figured that the include filter didn't work this way..

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable DEBUG logging to check that your initailizing bean isn't created twice, as Tobb mentioned before your bean is probabbly created in both contexts. Log stands clearly that first insert is executed during root context initialization (witch is correct) and second time during servlet context initialization (which is wrong)

I have found solution to your problem: You have to add commponent scan without default filters to your root-context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.db" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

and servlet-context is

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project.db" />
```

I have tested your project and its working fine with this change.

Comment: I've made changes as suggested, insertion of data looks fine but  now I'm seeing __HTTP Status 404 - Page not found__  with warning saying `WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/db/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springDispatcher'
`

Comment: After making changes according to my edit it works fine!